# Prompt for confirmation for every command

Tags: bash, shell-script, prompt, interactive

I'm writing a pretty ad-hoc install script for some thing. No much control constructs, basically just a list of commands. I'd like the user to confirm each command before it gets executed. Is there a way to let bash do that, without prefixing every command with a shell function name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `extdebug`:

```
shopt -s extdebug
trap '
  IFS= read -rn1 -d '' -p "run \"$BASH_COMMAND\"? " answer <> /dev/tty 1>&0
  echo > /dev/tty
  [[ $answer = [yY] ]]' DEBUG

cmd1
cmd2
...
```

For reference, the `zsh` equivalent would be:

```
TRAPDEBUG() {
  read -q "?run \"$ZSH_DEBUG_CMD\"? " || setopt errexit
  echo > /dev/tty
}
cmd1
cmd2
...
```

More portably:

```
run() {
  printf '%s ' "run $@?" > /dev/tty
  IFS= read -r answer < /dev/tty
  case $answer in
    [yY]*) "$@";;
  esac
}
run cmd1
run cmd2
run cmd3 > file
```

Beware that in `run cmd3 > file`, the `file` will be truncated even if you say `n`. So you may want to write it:

```
run eval 'cmd3 > file'
```

Or move the `eval` to the `run` function as in:

```
run() {
  printf '%s ' "run $@?" > /dev/tty
  IFS= read -r answer < /dev/tty
  case $answer in
    [yY]*) eval "$@";;
  esac
}
run cmd1
run 'cmd2 "$var"'
run 'cmd3 > file'
```

Another portable one, but with even more limitations:

```
xargs -pL1 env << 'EOF'
cmd1 "some arg"
cmd2 'other arg' arg\ 2
ENV_VAR=value cmd3
EOF
```

It only works for commands (ones found in `$PATH`), and arguments can only be literal strings (no variable or any shell structure, though xargs understand some forms of quoting of its own), and you can't have redirections, pipes...